# CheckboxListTitle trouble

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have a problem with my code. I want to control with a checkboxListTitle a list from an http request, as you know in the value: only true or false values are supported, however what I have is a string data type (0 false and 1 True). How could I fix this?, the closest I have been is with this code, but this way it only allows me to check or uncheck, not both at the same time and I can not see the real status of each data.

How could I treat each string in the list as a boolean so as not to lose this logic?

```
 `Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(baseurl + 'gettipo.php'),
        body: {"categoria": widget.tipo});
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async {
        setState(() {
          getData();
        });
      },
      child: FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ItemList(
                  list: snapshot.data!,
                )
              : Center(
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  ItemList({required this.list});

  @override
  State<ItemList> createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
 


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


value: widget.list[index]['ocultar'] != 0,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                widget.list[index]['ocultar'] = 0;
              });`
```

Comment: Check box list tile has 3 options for the value since the value is nullable. I do not fully understand your question though cause you only want two state but then you said this implementation doesn't work because it can only be check or unchecked?

Comment: Let me explain, what the HTTP request returns to me is a JSON type string, and the value "hide" returns 0 if it is false and >0 if it is true, my question is how I could treat this data since they are not of type Boolean and Value: only supports Boolean

Comment: [{"id_prod":"15","nameprod":"refresco","descrip":"refresco gaseado","categoria":"cocteles","precio":"1000","popular":"0","fotourl":"","ocultar":"0"},{"id_prod":"49","nameprod":"Arroz moro","descrip":"Arroz a lo cubano con frijoles negros","categoria":"comida","precio":"250","popular":"0","fotourl":"","ocultar":"0"},{"id_prod":"55","nameprod":"","descrip":"","categoria":"","precio":"0","popular":"0","fotourl":"","ocultar":"0"},{"id_prod":"57","nameprod":"cappuccino","descrip":"cafe caliente con leche","categoria":"cafe","precio":"50","popular":"1","fotourl":"images\/coffee.jpg","ocultar":"0"},

Comment: You should be able to do !(octular == 0). This will return false due to the "!". Or look into ternary operators